# How can i overcome a decimal place issue when using int(float(x)?

Tags: python, type-conversion, mapreduce, mapper

I have a csv file that I am using that is made up of several fields.
I am adding the name fields - to get full name and then pulling out the price and qty fields - which are strings in the CSV file.

```
def mapper(self, key, value):
            fields = value.split(",")
            name = fields[6] + " " + fields[7]
            Price = int(float(fields[4]))
            Qty = int(fields[5])    
            avgPrice = (Price*Qty)
            yield name,avgPrice
```

my output is giving me

`Becca Nelson 25.0`

but i am missing the decimal places i think it is because I  have had to use int(float(x)

I want the output to be
`Becca Nelson 25.55`

How can i get around this?

Comment: when you call int you're "killing" de decimal point part, why would you call int in a variable that you want to be float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use standard python module [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) to accurately process real values.

```py
from decimal import Decimal


def mapper(self, value):
    fields = value.split(",")
    name = fields[6] + " " + fields[7]
    price = Decimal(fields[4])  # here
    qty = int(fields[5])    
    avg_price = price * qty
    return name, avg_price
```

Also I'd recommend you use [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) instead of string operations ([example](https://realpython.com/python-csv/)).

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir I will attempt this.